# Python: exceptions in assignments

Tags: python, exception

If I try the following code (in Python 3.2.2),

```
def f():
    raise Exception

x = f()
```

then it appears that `x` is untouched - it either remains undefined or keeps whatever value it had previously.  Is this behaviour guaranteed whenever the right hand side of an assignment throws an exception?  I realise this is a very basic question, but I can't find much information about how exactly assignment works.  More generally, is the entire right hand side always evaluated before anything relating to the assignment happens?  Is this even true when using `setattr`, assigning to an element of a list, or using tuple unpacking (i.e. something like `x, y = y, f()`)?

Comment: As far as I know, this is consistent (just tested on PyPy, it's the same there), but I've not seen any explicit statement that it must be the case.

Comment: Well, the absence of a formal specification makes this a bit hard (the C, C++, Java, JavaScript, etc. guys can just quote a formal spec). But pragmatically, none of the implementations deviate and the behaviour is important enough that implemenetations that do deviate would be called broken.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Python language reference specifies this:

http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

The right side is evaluated, then the left side, then the assignment itself happens.  Thus,

```
def x():
    print "x"
    fail()

def y():
    print "y"
    fail()

x().a = y()
```

is guaranteed to print "y" and fail with NameError; it will never raise "x", or attempt any assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The Python documentation concerning the [assignment statement](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assignment_stmt) does not explicitly say that the left hand side of an assignment is never touched when the right hand side raises an exception, but after reading this article, it seems to turn out that the only way to avoid the assignment is to raise an Exception.

**Conclusion**: the left hand side of an assignment is never touched if an exception is raised